# Building MailCore framework for iOS?

Tags: frameworks, build, mailcore

Hello I'm trying to build MailCore framework since two days... it's giving too many errors.
first it was giving 'config.h no such file' error. I downloaded another copy of MailCore and this one is giving two errors

1-target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

2-Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-928/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTargetBuildContext.m:1966

please help me out.. I'm sick of it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by implementing the instructions exactly what is told here... http://libmailcore.com/...
no need to build framework... just include the files in your project as told by the link I've mentioned and you are done...

Comment: does it supports ios 6 and armv7?
Also, can you just add the dylib as dependency ? why do you need to add the source - it makes it so much more complicated...

Comment: it should support but i'm not sure!! yes it is possible to add the dylib as dependency.. but to build the  fremework from MailCore is really hard. I spent two days but was unsuccessful, finally ended with this solution.

Comment: Follow the above url instructions, and it should work

Comment: Hi @Sikander I follow the instructions given in the  http://libmailcore.com/ but getting the error <libetpan/libetpan.h> file not found.Plz help me out.

Comment: Sometimes you've these kind of issues if your project name has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak to that "config.h" error:

Turns out you have to have MailCore in a folder with no spaces in the directory path.

See:  https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/issues/35

I moved the folder to `/Users/bill/Documents/dev/lib/MailCore` and was able to build the project there. Leaving MailCore at that location, I dragged the MailCore.xcodeproj file into my project (located elsewhere on the hard drive) and was able to compile my project.

Would be nice if someone would add this as a warning to to the directions [here](http://libmailcore.com/#iosadding)